# What is the difference between stream parameter and protocol parameter in socket function?

Tags: c, sockets

```
int socket(int domain, int type, int protocol);
```

As per i understood,

```
int domain;
```

This parameter is used for passing the address family or protocol family. I belive that there is no major difference betweent the address family and protocol family. We are using this for specifying the address type (IPV4 or IPv6).

```
int type;
```

This parameter is used for connection type such as UDP,TCP in network layer.

```
int protocol;
```

This parameter is used for the specifying the protocol  such as TCP,UDP.

and my question is

what is the difference between the 2nd and 3rd parameter? If we use the TCP protocol we will use the `SOCK_STREAM` , and if we use the UDP protocol we will use the `SOCK_DGRAM` in 2nd parameter. So why there is a need for two parameters in  this case? Why not we use a single parameter instead of two?

Comment: you have asked in a deleted question something about C and database, but your question was so imprecise that it got deleted. Please **be much more specific and precise when asking questions**. (e.g. at least, mention operating system and actual database software like MySQL or PostgreSQL or MongoDB etc...). And the above question about `SOCK_STREAM` is certainly lacking a Linux or a Posix tag, because *standard C99 (or C11) does not know about sockets* !!

Answer (score 1):

As per the man page the protocol is the sub type of a socket, for most of types there is no sub type but some types may additional subtypes.

For example you can specify protocol number if you have type raw socket.

`int fd = socket (PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_TCP);`

-MS

Comment: Yes socket is nothing but connecting two end points using client server technology, we can connect this using any protocols as you said. Then my question is actually why there is two separate parameters for connection stream and protocol type.

Comment: One reason I can think of is that this is done to provide more flexibility in applying filters to identify a endpoint for data communication. In better words **to make it future proof**

Comment: What you are trying to mean by "Identifying the end points". How they will identify using the stream type or protocol type

Comment: There will be someone who will register it self as upper layer handler for that perticular type. Identifying the end points means figuring out the handler for the data at each layer. For eg for tcp packet first layer is Ethernet then comes IP then comes TCP layer and then comes actual application who has registered it self as owner of data coming to that port number.